# conditional skip in python if

Tags: python, if-statement

i am trying for something like this

```
def scanthefile():
    x = 11
    if x > 5
        """ i want to come out of if and go to end of scanfile """
        print x

     return info
```

**update:**

if have to check for the content size of a file. and if the content size is larger than a value say 500 , then i should go to the end of the scanfile

Comment: `x = 11; if x > 5`?  That's always true.  What's the point of this?  Even with the update, the question makes very little sense.  Can you rewrite this question so it does make sense?   Could you -- for example -- delete the code that makes no sense?

Comment: This question is a **great** example on how not to ask. You should have asked "how do I check for the content size of a file in python" in the first place - not pasting some arbitrary, partial attempt to do it without telling what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, and I'm really unsure I do, you can just de-indent:

```
x = 11
if x > 5:
    pass # Your code goes here.
print x
```

Answer (score 2):

By "go to the end of file", do you mean "seek to the end of file"?  Then:

```
import os

   ...

if x > 5:
  thefile.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
```

If you mean something completely different, you'd better clarify!

Answer (score 2):

OK, so to answer your update:

```
import os

fn = 'somefile.txt'
thefile = open(fn, 'r')

# The next line check the size of the file. Replace "stat(fn).st_size" with your own code if you want.
if stat(fn).st_size > 500:
    thefile.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
# you are now at the end of the file if the size is > 500
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand the question is that you want to break out of an **if-statement**, which you can't.

You can however replace it with a  **while loop**:

```
def scanthefile():
    x = 11

    while x > 5:
        # do something here...
        if CONTENTSIZE > 500:
            break
        # do something else..
        break # Which will make the while loop only run once.

    return info
```